# Why do my changes not save in static css files in django?

Tags: python, css, django, server, django-staticfiles

They used to save before, but all of a sudden they do not. I even have DEBUG = True and I have django.contrib.staticfiles in my installed apps. I'm not really what code I should provide, so if anyone needs any, please ask, and I'll send you the code. Thank You!

Edit: So I've somewhat realized that the two times this has happened, was when I turned debug to false and back to true again.

Comment: So I've somewhat realized that the two times this has happened, was when I turned debug to false and back to true again.

Answer (score 2):

So I reached out to someone else, and realized that all I had to do was hard refresh the page. `Cmd+Shift+R` on a mac and `Ctrl+F5` on a windows machine.